# Custom Profile Center Public Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, soap-api

I am looking for a starting point on how to grab all public lists within the marketing cloud instance to show dynamically on my custom profile center that I am building. I am also looking to allow the subscriber to obviously be able to opt-in to these said public lists and return that information back to marketing cloud. I am currently using the boilerplate that has been resourced from here.

This also relates to grabbing all of the subscriber's non-hidden attributes that they have also.

Does grabbing these public lists and attributes include using SOAP API, or is there another way around using that like AMPscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the SSJS function that I use to retrieve all of the Publication Lists.  While it's not AMPscript, it can be translated:

```
function getAllPublicationLists() {

    var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "Publication");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "QueryAllAccounts", "True");

    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ID");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Category");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Client.ID");

    var reqParams = [0,0];
    var publications = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, reqParams);

    return publications;
}
```

If you just want the *Public* ones, here's a function for that:

```
function getAllPublicPublicationLists(mid) {

      var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "List");

      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ID");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ListName");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Description");

      var filter1 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter1, "Property", "Type");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter1, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter1, "Value", "Public");

      var filter2 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter2, "Property", "ListClassification");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter2, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter2, "Value", "PublicationList");

      var cfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LeftOperand", filter1);
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LogicalOperator", "AND");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "RightOperand", filter2);

      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", cfp);

      var clid = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ClientID");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(clid, "ID", mid);
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "ClientIDs", clid);

      var reqParams = [0, 0];
      var Lists = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, reqParams);

      return Lists;
}
```

To output them, you can iterate through the results like this:

```
var allPublicationLists = getAllPublicationLists();
for (var i in allPublicationLists) {
  Write("\n" + allPublicationLists[i]["ID"] + "|" +allPublicationLists[i]["Client"]["ID"] + "|" +allPublicationLists[i]["Name"]);
}
```

Then if you wanted to retrieve all of a subscriber's publications, then you can do something like this with the API Objects:

```
function getSubscriberLists(subscriberkey) {

    var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "ListSubscriber");

    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ListID");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "SubscriberKey");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Status");

    var filter = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "Property", "SubscriberKey");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter, "Value", subscriberkey);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", filter);

    var reqParams = [0,0];
    var subscriberLists = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, reqParams);

    return subscriberLists;
}
```

If you wanted to just get non-Publication lists:

```
function getAllLists(mid) {

      var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "List");

      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ID");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ListName");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Description");

      var filter1 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter1, "Property", "Type");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter1, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter1, "Value", "Public");

      var filter2 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter2, "Property", "ListClassification");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter2, "SimpleOperator", "notEquals");
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter2, "Value", "PublicationList");

      var cfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LeftOperand", filter1);
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LogicalOperator", "AND");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "RightOperand", filter2);

      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", cfp);

      var clid = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ClientID");
      Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(clid, "ID", mid);
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "ClientIDs", clid);

      var reqParams = [0, 0];
      var Lists = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, reqParams);

      return Lists;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! After grabbing all of the lists, how does it translate to showing on a landing page? Like if I wanted to show all of the lists that I grabbed.

Comment: I've updated my post to include a loop...  Some of this will be different with AMPscript.

Comment: Also added a function that retrieves only Public Publication lists

Comment: Awesome! I'll check to see if printing those out work. Is there a way to just grab "Lists" or is it just only publication lists?

Comment: You can change the ComplexFilterPart in `getAllPublicPublicationLists()` to retrieve Lists only.

Comment: Sorry, one question about the ComplexFilterPart, what part do I have to change within that part to show only just public lists and not publication lists? I'm very basic to SSJS but thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated my answer above to include a `getAllLists()` function.